# what's wrong with my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Id like it to return records where products_extrafield_id is not 14 , but it still RETURNS it in my results .. I'm using joins

```
SELECT op. * 
FROM 
  products_to_products_extra_fields AS p
  INNER JOIN orders_products AS op ON p.products_id = op.products_id
  INNER JOIN orders AS o ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE NOT 
EXISTS (

    SELECT * 
    FROM products_to_products_extra_fields
    WHERE
      p.products_id = op.products_id
      AND p.products_extra_fields_id = 14
  )
  AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN  '2013-11-29' AND  '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
  AND o.payment_method =  'Institutional Billing'
  AND o.orders_status <100001
GROUP BY o.orders_id
ORDER BY DECODE( o.cc_type,  'oFsAfHr7' ) ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: is there an error message or it just doesn't work ?

Answer (score 3):

If I am reading your SQL correctly, then you don't need a NOT EXISTS clause to do this.  Just replace the NOT EXISTS clause with the following statement:   p.products_extra_fields_id != 14

```
SELECT 
    op. * 
FROM 
    products_to_products_extra_fields AS p
    INNER JOIN orders_products AS op 
    ON p.products_id = op.products_id
    INNER JOIN orders AS o 
    ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
    WHERE 
        p.products_extra_fields_id != 14
    AND o.date_purchased BETWEEN  '2013-11-29' AND  '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
    AND o.payment_method =  'Institutional Billing'
    AND o.orders_status <100001
GROUP BY o.orders_id
ORDER BY DECODE( o.cc_type,  'oFsAfHr7' ) ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Comment: was about to reply the same with the modified query... added it to your response. hope that is fine...

Comment: What's the data type of `products_extra_fields_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Why are you GROUPing without using aggregate functions?  Also, why would try to GROUP BY a field that is not in your SELECT?  I added the DISTINCT operator, along with moving your logic around. You subquery was using criteria from the main/ outer query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.cc_type, op.* 
FROM  orders_products AS op 
  INNER JOIN orders AS o 
    ON op.orders_id = o.orders_id
WHERE o.date_purchased BETWEEN  '2013-11-29' AND  '2013-12-03 23:59:59'
  AND o.payment_method =  'Institutional Billing'
  AND o.orders_status <100001
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                  FROM products_to_products_extra_fields AS p
                  WHERE p.products_id = op.products_id
                    AND p.products_extra_fields_id = 14)
ORDER BY DECODE( o.cc_type,  'oFsAfHr7' ) ASC 
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```